# Concatenate rows of matrix with two separators

Tags: r, matrix, apply, paste, r-sp

My goal is to turn a matrix of coordinate pairs into a single character string with the coordinate pairs pasted together.  For example, I have the coordinates of a lines string:

```
 mat <- routes@lines[[9]]@Lines[[1]]@coords
 mat
          [,1]    [,2]
[1,] -122.4491 37.7698
[2,] -122.4519 37.7694
[3,] -122.4491 37.7698
```

Which I would like to convert into this:

```
"-122.4491,37.7698;-122.4519,37.7694;-122.4491,37.7698"
```

Where lat and lon of a single pair are separated by a comma, and pairs are separated by a semicolon.

```
apply(format(mat), 1, paste, sep=";", collapse = "")
```

does not produce the desired output.  How would one do this in R ?

Here is the sample data:

```
dput(mat)
structure(c(-122.4491, -122.4519, -122.4491, 37.7698, 37.7694, 
37.7698), .Dim = c(3L, 2L))
```

Comment: the_darkside, is this issue resolved? If so, please accept one of the many answers below (I suggest that Dan Hall's is the most direct given your problem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mat <- structure(c(-122.4491, -122.4519, -122.4491, 37.7698, 37.7694, 37.7698), .Dim = c(3L, 2L))
```

This is a matrix, with coordinates in two columns. You can just use one call to paste.

```
paste(mat[,1], mat[,2], sep = ",", collapse = ";")
# [1] "-122.4491,37.7698;-122.4519,37.7694;-122.4491,37.7698"
```

Here `sep` sets the delimiter between lat and long coordinates (cells in the same row), and `collapse` sets the delimiter between coordinate pairs (the delimiter between different rows).

Answer (score 2):

```
mat <- structure(c(-122.4491, -122.4519, -122.4491, 37.7698, 37.7694, 37.7698), .Dim = c(3L, 2L))
```

You were close. Your use of `apply` is appropriate, but because you are operating first row-wise, you need to worry about one delimiting first:

```
apply(mat, 1, paste, collapse=",")
# [1] "-122.4491,37.7698" "-122.4519,37.7694" "-122.4491,37.7698"
```

... and then combine all of those with a single external `paste`:

```
paste(apply(mat, 1, paste, collapse=","), collapse=";")
# [1] "-122.4491,37.7698;-122.4519,37.7694;-122.4491,37.7698"
```

Comment: you can just paste the columns together. `sep=","` will set the between column delimiter and `collapse=";"` will set the between row delimiter. There is no need for apply, or multiple calls to paste.

Comment: Curious to whomever downvoted, is there a reason? Downvotes are like "the finger", and giving them anonymously without suggestions or comments is a bit weak.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to convert to `data.frame` and then use `do.call`

```
do.call(paste, c(as.data.frame(mat), collapse=";", sep=","))
#[1] "-122.4491,37.7698;-122.4519,37.7694;-122.4491,37.7698"
```

Comment: This produces three comma-delimited strings, not semi-colon-delimited pairs of comma-delimited lat/long. I think you need to add `collapse=";"`.

Comment: @r2evans  I was looking at your `apply(mat, 1, paste, collapse=",")`.  If the second is the right one, then change it to `collapse`

Comment: Oh, ok ... I was using it as a demonstration, building the process. I should have been clearer. Thanks.

Comment: `do.call(paste, c(as.data.frame(mat), collapse=";",sep=","))`